# Query from two databases where a table might not exist in either of the databases

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Is there a way to select from multiple databases where the column being queried might or might not exist?

My current code is as follows:

```
SELECT Value FROM [database1].[dbo].[table_name] WHERE Name='job_name' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [database1].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='table_name')
UNION
SELECT Value FROM [database2].[dbo].[table_name] WHERE Name='job_name' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [database2].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='table_name')
```

Just to clarify, I am trying to query from two different databases.  Both databases should have the same schema, but might not have been fully initialized and so might not contain the table being queried.  I am trying to do this in one query.

Comment: This kind of thing is often a lot easier with a scripting language that interfaces with the database.  Just get the appropriate column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns` for your tables and go from there...

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: The table might not exist or column or both? The question title says table while the question itself talks about both table and column.

Comment: To answer the second question, when the table doesn't exist in one of the databases, there is an error saying I have an invalid object name since apparently the select statement tries to connect to the table before the where clause is triggered.

Comment: I already have this working in code, but I was trying to figure out a way to do it on the server to alleviate some stress on the local machine.

Comment: Once the table is created, it is assumed that all the columns were initialized properly, so each table should contain the columns Value and Name if the table exists.

Comment: The heart of the problem is that table names and column names are effectively part of the public API for a SQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names used in a query must exist at the time when the SQL optimizer tries to plan the execution of the query.  If they don't, you will get back rude messages about the relevant table or column not existing.  There isn't any standard way around this.  And it is highly unlikely there's a non-standard way around this either.

At least, no way around it that takes the query text verbatim.  If you're prepared to do the system catalog queries (either through the native system catalog tables or via the information schema, which is more or less standardized), then you can decide how to build the query at runtime, so that it has a maximal chance of succeeding.  This is an unusual requirement; few programs are designed to tolerate such deviations from the expected norm for the database to which they connect.

Comment: I have this requirement because databases are created as the application is run, since the application is run on any number of machines (due to synchronization).  So it's possible that a machine might crash as it is creating a database, leaving that database without full table information.

If there isn't a way to do this as you say and I don't receive a correct way to do this, I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: If the database has crashed and doesn't have full table information, do you really want the query to try to execute without some sort of error message?

Comment: The idea is I'm trying to avoid querying through each of the databases independently.  If the table doesn't exist, I won't give the user access to that database for obvious reasons.  This is why I would like for the above query to be able to skip over a database if it does not contain the given table.

Comment: The way SQL works, @Stuart, is that it assumes that the objects (tables, columns) mentioned in the query must exist.  SQL does not have provision for deducing whether a given table exists or contains the correct columns, other than via the information schema or the system catalogs.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA, as in the code I posted, to determine whether the table existed within a query of that table.  If I take the query and split it into two parts, one with the condition of table existence, and the other with the actual query, each part runs fine.

Comment: You would have to do it in stages - one interrogating the information schema and then (assuming you find what you're looking for) the actual data.  Trying to combine the options won't work if the tables are missing - and only slows everything down if they are there.